# Problems Building .Net Core on TFS

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, .net-core

I have a solution containing multiple .Net Core projects, some of which are dependent on other projects in the same solution. The whole solution is hosted in a Git repository of an on-premises TFS server.

I want to set up an automated build process on the TFS server. For lack of better knowledge, I use the Visual Studio build template and leave all the settings on their defaults. When I run the build process, it fails on the "Build solution" step with the error message

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets(262,5): error : Project MyProject does not have a lock file.
>
> Please run "dotnet restore" to generate a new lock file. [C:\TFSBuildAgent_work\6\s\MyProject\MyProject.xproj]

So I go ahead and create a PowerShell script with the content `dotnet restore` that I run before "Build solution" but after "Nuget restore". This also fails, this time on step "Dotnet restore" with the error message

> Errors in C:\TFSBuildAgent_work\6\s\MyProject\project.json
>
> Unable to resolve 'ProjectDependency (>= 1.0.0)' for '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1'.

When I run `dotnet restore` on my local machine, it completes without any issues.

Any help or hints are greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you have multiple projects in your solution, you need to run `dotnet restore` for each of them.
Also, try deleting project.json.lock file on your local machine and re-run `dotnet restore` just for testing. Do you have the same .NET and .NET Core framework versions installed on both machines?

Comment: dotnet --info gives `1.0.0-preview2-003131` for the CLI tools on both machines, the .Net framework versions are the same too. `dotnet restore` steps into all subfolders. I deleted the `.lock.json` file, `dotnet restore` still works on my local machine.

Comment: you can do `dotnet --verbose restore`... to get more detailed output

Comment: I helped myself now in packaging the project dependency and uploading it to my inhouse package server. `dotnet restore` will then pull it from the server and build the whole project. Not the nicest way, but at least it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I helped myself now in packaging the project dependency and uploading it to my inhouse package server. `dotnet restore` will then pull it from the server and build the whole project. Not the nicest way, but at least it's working.